# MarkLogic Node.js. How to specify multiple collections in the query

Tags: marklogic

I am using MarkLogic Node.js Client API. I am running a query in which I want to specify multiple collections; but I am getting zero results. However, if I specify just one collection; the query works. Below is the example with one collection:

Collections: **test1** and **test2**

Query with **1** collection: **Works**

```
db.documents.query(
        qb.where(
            qb.collection("test1"),
            qb.value("productId","8989")
        ))
        .result();
```

Please help as how I can specify two collections?

Below query returns **zero results**:

```
db.documents.query(
        qb.where(
            qb.collection("test1"),qb.collection("test2"),
            qb.value("productId","8989")
        ))
        .result();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "fails", do you mean that the query returns no results, or an error?

Constraints in `qb.where` are `and`'d together, so the following only matches documents in both collections:

```
qb.where(
  qb.collection("test1"),
  qb.collection("test2")
)
```

To match documents in either collection, you need an `or` query:

```
qb.where(
  qb.or(
    qb.collection("test1"),
    qb.collection("test2")
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. I was not getting error but zero results. Now I am using qb.or (statement)

Comment: I am pretty sure you can also provide the two collection names as an array, like: `qb.collection(['test1', 'test2'])`. The node.js guide is not very clear about this, but the underlying structured-query supports it.